# How do I set certain column headers to be immovable in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing

I have an existing JTable and I want the first 3 columns of the table to be immovable. Meaning if the user tries to drag the table headers of any the first 3 columns, they won't move and shouldn't move at all but they can reorder the rest of the columns.

Something similar to what the line below does

```
myTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
```

but it only applies to certain columns and not all column headers.

I tried using a work around by utilizing mouse listeners so when the user hovers the mouse over any of the first 3 columns, I just disable the reordering for the entire table like below so they are unable to drag it.

```
myTable.getTableHeader().addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
                        int column = myTable.columnAtPoint(me.getPoint());
                        if(column < 3) myTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
                        else myTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(true);
                    }
});
```

It does prevent the user from dragging the first 3 columns. However, the issue is the user can still drag the other columns anywhere in the column order. They can drag say column #8 before column #2 and now the first 3 columns are different. The furthest column position the user should be able to move column #8 is right after column#3.

What is the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: One idea would be to have two `JTables` that use the same table model.  The first `JTable` would consist of the three columns and be locked.  The second `JTable` would consist of the remaining columns and be flexible.  Both `JTables` would be placed in a single `JPanel` using a `BorderLayout`.  The `JPanel` would be placed in a `JScrollPane`.

Comment: I'm working with an existing codebase right now and trying to do that would require too much modification of code everywhere else and I'm also very limited on time. Need something where I can just add code to the table rather than restructuring the entire thing.

Comment: Check out [Fixed Column Table](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/fixed-column-table/) for a reusable class that should meet your needs,

Answer (score 0):

You can override [moveColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html#moveColumn(int,int)) in the column model and [setDraggedColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/JTableHeader.html#setDraggedColumn(javax.swing.table.TableColumn)) in the table header:

```
    JTable table = /* ... */;
    int lastFixedColumn = 2;

    TableColumnModel columnModel = new DefaultTableColumnModel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

        @Override
        public void moveColumn(int fromIndex,
                               int toIndex) {

            if (fromIndex > lastFixedColumn) {
                super.moveColumn(fromIndex,
                    Math.max(toIndex, lastFixedColumn + 1));
            }
        }
    };
    int numCols = table.getModel().getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(i);
        column.setHeaderValue(table.getModel().getColumnName(i));
        columnModel.addColumn(column);
    }

    JTableHeader header = new JTableHeader(columnModel) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

        @Override
        public void setDraggedColumn(TableColumn column) {
            if (column == null ||
                column.getModelIndex() > lastFixedColumn) {

                super.setDraggedColumn(column);
            }
        }
    };

    table.setTableHeader(header);
    table.setColumnModel(columnModel);
```